# asp.net foreach row in dataset make a balloon with text

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, database, list

I got a question for you guys.

- How do I Dynamicly add an item to asp.net?
- there a way to make a balloon looking box of text?

I know how to get items into ds from database and fill it up and read it for each row there is. but that does not help me alot when I want to make dynamicly some stuff and get a ballon view of text just like if you are looking at your phone and see the text messeges thats how I want it to look like.

I took a example of my code where I show how I fill the dataset and how I bind the data into a Gridview

DBControl.cs

```
    public DataSet GetData(String queryString)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            //run the query.
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, m_helpdeskconnection);

            // Fill the DataSet.
            adapter.Fill(ds);

        }
        catch
        {

            // The connection failed. Display an error message.

            //Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database.";
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

AdministrerBrugere.aspx.cs

```
    DBControl db = new DBControl();
    String queryString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            queryString = "SELECT KundeNr, Navn FROM Kunder";
            BindData();
        }
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        // Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
        // to the GridView control.
        db.ConnOpenHelpdesk();
        DataSet ds = db.GetData(queryString);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        db.ConnCloseHelpdesk();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a DataRepeater to bind your content and use an ItemTemplate that has a CSS styled DIV to make it look like a baloon.

Try these links:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

Comment: okay :) The itemtemplate is just what I was looking for and I will surely take a look at the datarepeater :) ty for the fast reply