# CSS3 Borders with Repeater with different attributes out from database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I got my previous answer claered up and got it how I wanted but I want something more to it I want a little twist :)
Right now I use
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp togetter with http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

What I want is when I read from my database I have a section called answered with a tinyint 1/2 if 1 its answered from and admin if 2 its from a user. I want my css3 borders to be in the left side with the 1 and at the right side with the 2. And if possible have a grayish/blue color.

[image]

previeus question: [asp.net foreach row in dataset make a balloon with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502965/asp-net-foreach-row-in-dataset-make-a-balloon-with-text)

my code looks like this

Side.aspx

```
                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="cdcatalog">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div style="border: 2px solid #a1a1a1; padding: 10px 40px; background: #dddddd; width: 300px; border-radius: 25px;">
                                            <asp:Table runat="server">
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <p style="text-align:left; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;"><%# Eval("TimeStamp")%></p>
                                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <%# Eval("Tekst")%>
                                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                            </asp:Table>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```

Side.aspx.cs

```
    DBControl db = new DBControl();
    String queryString2;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        queryString2 = "SELECT * FROM Samtaler WHERE TicketID=" + Session["ValgtTicket"].ToString() + "";
        BindRepeater();
    }

    private void BindRepeater()
    {
        // Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
        // to the GridView control.
        db.ConnOpenHelpdesk();
        DataSet ds = db.GetData(queryString2);
        cdcatalog.DataSource = ds;
        cdcatalog.DataBind();

        db.ConnCloseHelpdesk();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make it all inside the codebehind with a asp:panel

here is the link that I used

http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Repeater-dynamically-using-C-sharp-code.aspx